# How can I set single line spacing for \enumerate amd \section?

Tags: formatting, lists, line-spacing, sections-paragraphs

I want to set `\enumerate` and `\section` to use single line spacing and small font like the table of content in this [document](http://ctan.mirror.rafal.ca/macros/latex/contrib/todonotes/todonotes.pdf). How can I do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package to change the formatting for the section headings, and the [`enumitem`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to kill all extra vertical space in the enumerate environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\bfseries}
\titlespacing*{\section}
  {0pt}{3.5ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0.3ex plus .2ex}

\setlist[enumerate]{nolistsep}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\begin{enumerate}
\item First item.
\item Second item.
\item Third item.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]